# php header method doesn't work when location comes from a function

Tags: php, header

On a page on I'm working on, it can be password protected, so a user would have to login before they can see the content. After they login the following code is called:

```
//In one file
function current_page_url() {
    return 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

//In Another file
generate_page_cookie();
header('Location: ', current_page_url());
exit;
```

Which doesn't work. The following however does:

```
generate_page_cookie();
header('Location: ', 'http://example.com');
exit;
```

It seems strange that using a string in the header function works, but a function call within the header function doesn't.

I think it might have something to do with accessing the $_SERVER variable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: FYI: You're missing the protocol, the port and the query string in your function. Also you should validate the input before using it inside the header call.

Comment: Where I'm using this code I don't need the port and query string. The protocol will always be ```http```. The ```current_page_url``` function isn't finished yet.

Comment: I just was adding it as a comment, because taking your question title literally one might expect to find a full function here. Just noting.

Comment: Yeah. Just wanted to clarify. Thanks for the input though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `,` to `.`, php use `.` to concat strings.

```
header('Location: ' . current_page_url());
```

Comment: Ha, I checked every bar the typo. Thanks!